# css3 inset shadow has crisp edge

Tags: css

[image]

at the rounded corner, it has crisp edge, is this normal?

```
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0px 2px #FFF;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0px 2px #FFF;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0px 2px #FFF;
```

I tried border method, doesn't seem to be improved..

Comment: I don't see your crisp edge? Can you create the jsFiddle?

Comment: the third property is the 'blur' value and you have that set to `0px` so it will always be crisp. Increase this value to blur it. e.g. `inset 0 0 5px 2px`

Comment: You should also note that if you're trying to apply an inset box shadow directly to an image it will not work. You have to use other techniques to achieve that.

Comment: @Novocaine88 no, it's a div, I apply it with background.. how possible inset box shadow can be apply on a image..

Comment: I'm not sure of the technique needed to apply this to an image, I just know I've come across the issue before. A good google should tell you how to apply inset box shadows to images.

Comment: @Novocaine88 I did that, otherwise you won't see my image has an inset border